# How to add custom field to wp_list_table

Tags: table, list, wp-list-table

I am trying build my own wp_list_table. And i am using this following code:
https://github.com/pmbaldha/WP-Custom-List-Table-With-Database-Example/blob/master/custom-list-table-db-example.php

It is works fine. But i want to add my custom fields. So i add this lines:

```
<?php 
    public function get_columns() {
        $columns = array(
            'cb'     => '<input type="checkbox" />',
            'name'   => __('Name', 'cltd_example'),
            'email'  => __('E-Mail', 'cltd_example'),
            'age'    => __('Age', 'cltd_example'),
            'custom' => __('Custom', 'cltd_example'), // Added this line
        );
        return $columns;
    }
?>
```

And:

```
<?php
function get_sortable_columns() {
    $sortable_columns = array(
        'name'   => array('name', true),
        'email'  => array('email', false),
        'age'    => array('age', false),
        'custom' => array('custom', false), // Added this line
    );
    return $sortable_columns;
}
?>
```

And

```
<?php
    $default = array(
        'id'     => 0,
        'name'   => '',
        'email'  => '',
        'age'    => null,
        'custom' => '', // Added this line
    );
?>
```

And added this into form:

```
<input id="custom" name="custom" type="text" style="width: 95%" value="<?php echo esc_attr($item['custom']); ?>" size="50" class="code" placeholder="<?php _e('Custom', 'cltd_example');?>" required>
```

But when i try to save new value, it says error. What is wrong?

Comment: There is no code responsible for save in the question.

Comment: have you add your custom field in the database table?

Comment: No :) but it  add datatables with plugin activation. I am using it in theme function. I don't know how to add database fields in theme.